# Custom response header in PHP/Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, redirect, pjax

I'd like to set a custom response header such that I can use [PJAX (ajax+pushState)](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) to submit forms.

My basic use case is a login form (http://mySite.com/login) which redirects to the user's library (http://mySite.com/library) on success.

I need to set the header to `X-PJAX-URL: http://mysite.com/library` in order for PJAX to redirect the URL to library but unfortunately using [CI's output class functionality](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/output.html) isn't working for me:

```
$this->output->set_header('X-PJAX-URL: http://mySite.com/library');
redirect('library');
```

Nor does this:

```
$output='X-PJAX-URL: http://mySite.com/library';
$this->output->append_output($output);
redirect('library');
```

So the problem is that the redirect to `library`'s content occurs but the URL remains `login`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$this->output->set_header('X-PJAX-URL: http://mySite.com/library', false);
$this->output->set_header('Location: ' . site_url('library'), false);
```

Or try it

```
header('X-PJAX-URL: http://mySite.com/library');
header('Location: ' . site_url('library'), false);
```

Comment: -@Winston, didn't work. The header `'Location: ' . site_url('library')` is working fine. It's the custom header part that isn't working.

Comment: Hmm... Try my last update yet.. I don't know what is your problem. I trying your custom header on localhost and it works fine http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20130227-tbzg-99kb

Comment: hmm, you're right. I can set the custom pjax header if I just apply it to a random controller function. The problem seems to be for my particular scenario is that its actually 2 requests/responses. One to login to check the login credentials and then a 2nd one to redirect to library. Not sure what to do about this...

Comment: But you can set header before do second redirect to library

Comment: -@Winston, yeah but all i'm saying is it doesn't work if try and do the redirect with the login controller function like this: https://gist.github.com/tim-peterson/5051116

Comment: What if you set `header()` in your `__consruct()` method of `Account` class? Or this bad idea?

Comment: hmm, setting `header()` in the `__construct()` had no effect. i think i'm gonna quit for now but thanks for your help. Will let you know if I figure anything out. Thanks again!

Comment: OK. If you're find solution let me know how do you did it.